# How Can I Safely Manage wxPython Progress Dialog Threading?

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, popup, thread-safety, wxpython

I have several calculations to run without any user input and without the user worrying about the program having frozen, so I am trying to show a progress bar popup to keep them aware of what's happening.

Looking around has lead me to believe that I need to use a separate thread to do this, and I came up with this example.

```
import threading, wx, time

MAX_INT = 10
TEST_TUPLE = [[11, 22],[33,44]]

class mainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, ID, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, ID, title)
        bt = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_OK)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onBt, bt)

    def onBt(self,event):
        self.dlg = wx.ProgressDialog("title", "message", maximum=MAX_INT)
        workThread = threading.Thread(target=self.doWork, args=(TEST_TUPLE,) )
        workThread.start()
        self.dlg.ShowModal()

    def doWork(self, testArg):
        # time consuming stuff that affects main GUI
        print testArg
        for i in range(1, MAX_INT+1):
            self.SetPosition((i*4*MAX_INT, i*2*MAX_INT))
            time.sleep(1)
            print str(i)+" of "+str(MAX_INT)
            wx.CallAfter(self.dlg.Update, i, "%i of %i"%(i, MAX_INT))
        self.dlg.Destroy()


app = wx.App(False)
fr = mainFrame(None, -1, "Title")
fr.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

It seems to work as intended, but is there some housekeeping that I am skipping here?

EDIT: I replaced the dialog with a miniframe so the main window would not freeze, disabled the button so there wouldn't be several frames spawned, and added a crude cancelling method.

```
import threading, wx, time

MAX_INT = 10
TEST_TUPLE = [[11, 22],[33,44]]

class GaugeFrame(wx.MiniFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title, maximum):
        wx.MiniFrame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(200, 60) )

        self.bar = wx.Gauge(self, range=maximum)
        self.buCancel = wx.Button(self, label="Cancel")
        self.SetBackgroundColour("LTGRAY")

        siMainV = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        siMainV.Add(self.bar)
        siMainV.Add(self.buCancel, flag=wx.CENTER)
        self.SetSizer(siMainV)
        self.Fit()

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onCancel, self.buCancel)

    def updateGauge(self, value, message=""):
        self.bar.SetValue(value)
        if message!="":
            self.SetTitle(message)

    def onCancel(self, e):
        self.SetTitle("Cancelling...")

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, ID, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, ID, title)
        self.bt = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_OK)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onBt, self.bt)

    def onBt(self, event):
        self.gFr = GaugeFrame(self, title="0 of "+str(MAX_INT), maximum=MAX_INT)
        self.gFr.Show()
        self.gFr.Center()
        self.bt.Disable()
        workThread = threading.Thread(target=self.doWork, args=(TEST_TUPLE,) )
        workThread.start()

    def doWork(self, testArg):
        # time consuming stuff that affects main GUI
        print testArg
        for i in range(1, MAX_INT+1):
            time.sleep(1)
            if self.gFr.GetTitle()=="Cancelling...":
                break
            print str(i)+" of "+str(MAX_INT)
            wx.CallAfter(self.gFr.updateGauge, i, "%i of %i"%(i, MAX_INT))
        wx.CallAfter(self.gFr.Destroy)
        wx.CallAfter(self.bt.Enable)


app = wx.App(False)
fr = MainFrame(None, -1, "Title")
fr.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks pretty good, just a couple of observations.

- You should not call ANY window functions on the worker thread. This includes `SetPosition` and `Destroy`. You can use `wx.CallAfter` to invoke these on the main thread just like you are for `Update`.
- You probably should allow the user to cancel the processing.