# Displaying Progress with wxPython

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

I'm hoping someone will be able to give me a hand displaying the progress for a long running task using wxPython.

I currently have a function, which is invoked by a button, and executes 5 other functions e.g.

```
def sum(self, event):
    self.processSents()
    self.processWords()
    self.repSents()
    self.measSim()
    self.selCont()
```

I would like to display a progress bar while these functions are being executed, as the program sometimes hangs which isn't ideal.

A lot of the solutions I've looked at suggest threading, but I'm pretty inexperienced with threads in Python, and my attempts are getting me nowhere fast. I'm not sure for example, if the dialog should be in the thread, the executing code, or both.

My current attempt is as follows:

```
def sum(self, event):
    progress = wx.ProgressDialog("sum in progress", "please wait", maximum=100, parent=self, style=wx.PD_SMOOTH|wx.PD_AUTO_HIDE)
    self.Start(self.DoWork, progress)
    progress.ShowModal()

def Start(func, *args):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=func, args=args)
    thread.setDaemon(True)
    thread.start()

def DoWork(self, progress):
    for i in range(101):
        ex.CallAfter(progress.Update, i)
        time.sleep(0.2)
    self.processSents()
    self.processWords()
    self.repSents()
    self.measSim()
    self.selCont()
    wx.CallAfter(progress.Destroy)
```

The solutions I've looked at so far are:

[Updating a wxPython progress bar after calling app.MainLoop()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6943339/updating-a-wxpython-progress-bar-after-calling-app-mainloop)

[How to thread wxPython progress bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13654559/how-to-thread-wxpython-progress-bar)

[How Can I Safely Manage wxPython Progress Dialog Threading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20012542/how-can-i-safely-manage-wxpython-progress-dialog-threading)

http://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks

Any help or advice would be appreciated as I'm pretty lost :(

Thanks

Chris

**Updated to working version (combination of Jerry's response combined with wx.Yield() as recommended by Corley**

```
def sum(self, event):
    progress = wx.ProgressDialog("sum in progress", "please wait", maximum=100, parent=self, style=wx.PD_SMOOTH|wx.PD_AUTO_HIDE)
    self.processSents()
    percent = 20
    progress.Update(percent)
    self.processWords()
    percent += 20
    progress.Update(percent)

    // repSends, measSim and selCont omitted to save space
    progress.Destroy()
```

wx.Yield() is called from within each function e.g.

```
def processSents(self):
    // some long running process
    wx.Yield()
    // end of long running process
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possibly simpler option is just to call `wx.Yield()` periodically in your code; this allows the GUI to refresh/process inputs. Of course, nothing else will run, but it does allow your progress bar to update properly.

The progress bar should probably be a global, or passed to the subfunctions, so that it can update the progress as it goes.

Comment: Hi Corley, is it possible to call wx.Yield() from a separate class? i.e. I have my GUI in one class, and the long running code is in another class, so wx.Yield() would need to be called from within the long running code. Is this doable or would wx.Yield() need to be called from within the GUI class? thanks

Comment: `wx.Yield()` can be called from anywhere, and should be called from the long-running code.

Answer (score 2):

1) Thread `DoWork` would be created when you click the button.

2) In `DoWork`, another thread `showProgress` would be created to display the progress dialog

3）In `DoWork`, `doSomething` simulate some time-consuming thing

4) Aonther thread `updateProgress` would be created before each `doSomething` in this sample to avoid the progress bar freeze,  but actually you should call `self.progress.Update` to update the progress bar while your `sum progress`

```
import wx
import threading
import  time

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,None)
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        btn1 = wx.Button(panel, label="test1")
        btn1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onButton1)

        btn2 = wx.Button(panel, label="test2")
        btn2.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onButton2)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        sizer.Add(btn1)
        sizer.Add(btn2)

        panel.SetSizer(sizer)


        self.maxPercent = 100
        self.percent = 0

    def onButton1(self, evt):
        self.StartThread(self.DoWork1)

    def onButton2(self, evt):
        self.StartThread(self.DoWork2)

    def StartThread(self, func, *args):
        thread = threading.Thread(target=func, args=args)
        thread.setDaemon(True)
        thread.start()

    def showProgress(self):
        self.progress = wx.ProgressDialog("sum in progress", "please wait", maximum=self.maxPercent, parent=self, style=wx.PD_SMOOTH|wx.PD_AUTO_HIDE)

    def destoryProgress(self):
        self.progress.Destroy()

    def updateProgress(self, percent):
        keepGoing = True
        time.sleep(1)
        while keepGoing and self.percent < percent:
            self.percent += 1
            (keepGoing, skip) = self.progress.Update(self.percent)
            time.sleep(0.1)


    def doSomething(self, take_time, taskPercent, say_something):
        time.sleep(take_time)
        (keepGoing, skip) = self.progress.Update(taskPercent, say_something+" done!")


    def DoWork1(self):
        self.StartThread(self.showProgress)

        taskPercent = 25
        self.StartThread(self.updateProgress, taskPercent)
        self.doSomething(5, taskPercent, "1st")

        taskPercent +=25
        self.StartThread(self.updateProgress, taskPercent)
        self.doSomething(5, taskPercent, "2nd")

        taskPercent +=25
        self.StartThread(self.updateProgress, taskPercent)
        self.doSomething(5, taskPercent, "3rd")

        taskPercent +=25
        self.StartThread(self.updateProgress, taskPercent)
        self.doSomething(5, taskPercent, "4th")

        self.destoryProgress()

    def DoWork2(self):
        self.StartThread(self.showProgress)

        taskPercent = 25
        self.doSomething(5, taskPercent, "1st")

        taskPercent +=25
        self.doSomething(5, taskPercent, "2nd")

        taskPercent +=25
        self.doSomething(5, taskPercent, "3rd")

        taskPercent +=25
        self.doSomething(5, taskPercent, "4th")

        self.destoryProgress()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = wx.App(0)
    frame = MyFrame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jerry. I tried your code (with no changes) but after the progress dialog closes the program hangs and I am no longer able to select the main window. Also am I understanding point 4 correctly, in thinking my code should essentially look like this: 

`def DoWork(self)

self.StartThread(self.showProgress)

taskPercent=25

self.progress.Update(taskPercent)

self.processSents()`

i.e. remove the updateProgress and doSomething methods?

Comment: @chrisrs2292 Sorry, App hang because I forgot to destory the dialog. Another case added in the code `without updateProgress` , you can check the difference. `self.progress.Update` would be performed in the end of each `doSomething`

Comment: Ah thank you, the app is not hanging anymore, but for some reason the progressdialog is now closing before the code has finished executing. I'm updating my original post with some of the more recent code.

Comment: @chrisrs2292 please try to add some flags like `wx.PD_APP_MODAL`, I'm not able to run the code now, but I think this is what you need.

Comment: Hey Jerry, I tried to use wx.PD_APP_MODAL but the dialog still closes itself before the long running code is completed. So the issue I have is that within the selCont() function I display some output in a text control. But the progressDialog closes, and then the app just sits for 4-5 seconds on my tests before the output actually displays. Don't really know why this would happen when destroy is not called until after selCont() is finished executing =/